# Count and avg. with multi-level nesting in D3

Tags: arrays, json, d3.js, multidimensional-array

I'm building a table and I'm trying to add some calculated value in a new column. I've reproduced a sample data here : http://bl.ocks.org/simonbreton/dbb04f0d8123bc41fcb231497a276848

I would like to calculate the average daily number of rescue for each super hero. I've start with the following code :

```
avgdailyrescue = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .key(function(d) { return d.day;})
  .rollup(function(v) { return {
    count: v.length,
  }; })
  .entries(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(avgdailyrescue));
```

so I have this result :

```
[{"key":"batman","values":[{"key":"monday","values":{"count":1}}, {"key":"tuesday","values":{"count":2}}]},
{"key":"superman","values":[{"key":"friday","values":{"count":1}},{"key":"saturday","values":{"count":1}},{"key":"sunday","values":{"count":2}}]},
{"key":"ironman","values":[{"key":"sunday","values":{"count":2}},{"key":"wednesday","values":{"count":1}},{"key":"friday","values":{"count":1}},{"key":"monday","values":{"count":1}}]},
{"key":"Antman","values":[{"key":"monday","values":{"count":1}}]}]
```

but I don't really know what to do next... any idea, any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a good start. You just need to sum up total for each day, and divide by the count you already have:

```
var avgdailyrescue = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.name })
    .key(function(d) { return d.day })
    .rollup(function(byDay) {
        var count = byDay.length;
        var total = d3.sum(byDay, function(d) { return d.rescue })
        return total/count;
    })
    .entries(data)
```

Comment: it's an array of records with the same value for `name` and `day` properties (ie, per hero per day)